# Open subtab from Console Primary Tab Component

Tags: visualforce, javascript, console, custom-console-components

I have a custom VF Primary Tab Component (Right Sidebar) in the console. That is on the Account layout, this loads to the right with a load of Opportunity information.

The issue I am having is I want to be able to click on the Opportunity name, when this is done it should open the Opportunity as a subtab of the Account... however this is not working -_-

This is my JS:

```
<script>
var oppId;

function openPrimaryTab(opp){
    oppId = opp;
    sforce.console.getPrimaryTabIds(showTabId);
}

var showTabId = function showTabId(result) {
    sforce.console.openSubtab(result.ids, '/' + oppId + '?isdtp=vw', false, 'salesforce', openSuccess, 'salesforceTab');
};

var openSuccess = function openSuccess(result) {
    if (result.success == true) {
        alert('Primary tab successfully opened');
    } else {
        alert('Primary tab cannot be opened');
    }
};
</script>
```

Link: `<a href="#" onclick="openPrimaryTab('{!opp.Id}');return false">`

Would anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? I am stumped :/

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter into openSubtab requires a single primary tab ID. The value *result.ids* which is returned in the callback from getPrimaryTabIds is an array of IDs. So your call to openSubtab fails because it's getting invalid input.

If you want a single ID of the primary tab your component is loaded in, you can use the method getEnclosingPrimaryTabId.

Sample code can be found here 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_opensubtab.htm